# c# MonoDevelop - Modify a Label in a separate Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, label, monodevelop

i'm using MonoDevelop on Linux and i develop in c#.
I have this problem:

I would read string from serialPort. I saw that MonoDevelop don't start the SerialEventHandler, so i have found this solution:
implement a separate Thread which it's always run.
this is the code:

```
private static string locateQuad="";
private static void threadRead ()
{
    string indata="";
    while (true) {
        if(isOpenSerial==true){
            try{
            indata=sp.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine ("dati ricevuti "+indata);
            locateQuad=indata;
            }
            } catch (Exception e){
                Console.WriteLine("IOException");
            }
        }
    }
}
Thread th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(threadRead));
```

Now i would modify my Label with the value `indata` or `locateQuad` but I can't invoke this.label.text because I can't use `this` inside a method declared static, also I can't declare the method invoked by the thread non-static.

this is a Dog that eats its own tail!!!!!!!

So, i hope you have a solution. 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is because .Net is thread-safe. You cannot do operations on a thread using another thread. So, you have to use Delegates, Invokes and others methods.

### 1. Using a simple Invoke method.

You can modify a control which is on a separated thread using Invoke statement. This looks like this :

```
Invoke(new Action(() => {this.label1.Text = "Text modified using Invoke.";}));
```

This method is the one I preferer because it is really fast and easy. 
You can replace the content into the `{ }` by what you want, i.e you can change the ForeColor, add components in the Form and many other things. In your case, you can assign a value to another thread-variable. :)

### 2. Using delegates method

Delegates method is more complicated and I don't like to use them. But, you can anyway use them. There is a good tutorial about Delegates : http://www.dotnetperls.com/delegate. I will not copy/paste the code here so take a while and look about Delegates ;)

Comment: Sorry but i don't use VisualStudio. I'm in MonoDevelop.
Your solution I have already tried it and it doesn't work :(

Comment: one possibile use is 
Gtk.Application.Invoke(new System.Action(() => {this.numeroQuadrante1.Text = locateQuad;})); 
but don't work.